# Differentiate between meeting request and message compose in Office.js

Tags: office-js

Currently Office.js lets you know if you are composing a meeting invite by accessing the `itemType` on `Office.context.mailbox.item.itemType`, this works fine for composing/creating a meeting as you get the expected `appointment` value back.

When an attendee however replies/forwards this invite, the itemType is treated as `message` which I can see some reason for doing so, but this makes it incredibly hard to reason on whether we should carry out some action when the item is sent as we do not know if it is related to a meeting invite at all.

Is there a way that, whilst the item is being composed, we can figure out if this is response to a meeting invite or an actual message?

I have tried accessing various properties like the meeting organizer and attendees but they are all undefined.

Answer (score 1):

So this isn't a purely Office.js specific way of doing it, but it works for the use case we have.

You will have to call `getCallbackTokenAsync()` and `restUrl` on the mailbox object, remembering to save the item first using `saveAsync()` on the item, this will give you the item ID and the endpoint for the current mailbox. You can then use the Outlook REST API to send a GET request to the following endpoint `${messageBaseUrl}?$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=PropertyId eq 'String 0x001A')"`

In the response you get back, there will be the following property which will contain the a value you can use to check the type of the item beyond what Office.js makes available to you;

```
"SingleValueExtendedProperties": [
  {
    "PropertyId": "String 0x1a",
    "Value": "IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Request"
  }
]
```

In the case of the response above, I was attempting to forward the meeting invite to someone else and whilst Office.js reported an itemType of `message` you can see the MAPI property we requested told us it is actually a meeting request.

Ideally this would be made available in the Office.js API at some point with the itemType becoming a little more accurate but this seems to be a sufficient work around for now.

All types of messages classes and item types can be found; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/forms/item-types-and-message-classes